# Retrofit2. Как получить объект JSON в котором содержится массив?

Tags: android, retrofit

У меня следующая схема JSON.

```
{
"ID":"48213",
"TIMESTAMP_X":"23.10.2015 23:45:52",
"TIMESTAMP_X_UNIX":"1445633152",
"PHOTOALBUM":[
              "20906",
              "20907",
              "20908",
              "20909",
              "20923",
              "20924"
            ],
 "CITY_BIND":false,
"SECTION_NAME":null
}
```

Когда делаю запросы в которых нет вложенного массива все хорошо, а вот этот запрос сделать не могу.
Пробовал через такой клаcc:

```
public class Example {

*
*
private List<String> PHOTOALBUM = new ArrayList<String>();



public List<String> getPHOTOALBUM() {
return PHOTOALBUM;
 }


}
```

Но не работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться вот этим сервисом
http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/
получить класс с Jackson анотациями
и использовать ретрофит с соответствующим конвертером
com.squareup.retrofit:converter-jackson
Либо использовать др. анотиции и конвертеры.
PS
А в вашем примере, вы setPHOTOALBUM не забыли добавить?

Comment: Не забыл. Как раз через http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ делал. Только без аннотаций. и конвертер com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson

Comment: Вот  public void setPHOTOALBUM(List<String> PHOTOALBUM) {
        this.PHOTOALBUM = PHOTOALBUM;
    }

Comment: В вот так объявлен private List<String> PHOTOALBUM = new ArrayList<String>();

Comment: @FredGan, Насчет аннотаций не понял. Вот смотрю результат для Gson там `@SerializedName("PHOTOALBUM")` и т.д.

Comment: @FredGan, у вас наверняка опечатка в коде где-то, либо класс для данных, либо подключение конвертера

Comment: Сейчас с генерировал с аннотациями Gson:
 @SerializedName("PHOTOALBUM")
    @Expose
    private List<String> PHOTOALBUM = new ArrayList<String>();

Comment: Все равно не получаю данных никаких.

Comment: Да и что конвертировать то? Данных нет.

Comment: Вот ведь. Реально опечатка.)